# How to view/edit a long URL?

Tags: chrome-for-android, editing

I have a long URL displayed in the URL box of Chrome on Android 11. I would like to view and edit it. When I use a pencil tool, only the last part of the URL is visible and accessible for editing. How to scroll left to the beginning of it? I tried two fingers with no effect.

Answer (score 6):

It mostly depends on the keyboard you use.

- If you use Gboard, there is no <kbd>HOME</kbd> key. But, you can use its Text Editing feature. The top arrow key mimics the <kbd>HOME</kbd> key. See recording below.
- If your keyboard has a <kbd>HOME</kbd> key like PC's keyboards do, then pressing the key will send you to the beginning of the URL.

[image]

Comment: I was using the UP key, as suggested in the answer, that used to work until a few days ago. Now it doesn't, and I have to drag the pencil icon for long seconds. Does anyone else has the same observation and found a way to restore the normal/efficient behavior?

Comment: @jbd It still works on my side. Gboard version 13.7.12.582282722-release-arm64-v8a. What version do you use?